# Redirecting https to http expect one url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, ssl, https

I was trying to redirect my webpage to normal http but one specific url should be redirect to https.

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^site-name\.html$ https://domain.com/site-name.html [L,R=301]
```

But this way, the normal website is reachable through http and https.

Maybe you guys can help me with that.

Comment: ok what's not working? Do you have other rules also in this .htaccess?

Comment: Its working this way. This site gets redirected to https

But also, all other sites are reachable through http and https (when i type in https://domain.com)

I want, that all other sites are only reachable through normal http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another to redirect `https->http` for all other pages:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^site-name\.html$ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^site-name\.html$ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```